# Print fields from file only if line starts with a specific word

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have the following file:

```
…
   LINK=dummy 172.17.100 => 10.218.11 [PATH=/etc]
      FILE=hosts 172.17.100 => 10.218.11 [PATH=/etc]
       FILE=network 172.17.100 => 10.218.11 [PATH=/etc/sysconfig]
     LINK=empty 172.17.100 => 10.218.11 [PATH=/etc]
   FILE#TEST 172.17.100 => 10.218.11 [PATH=/etc/sysconfig]
```

…

How to print the first field and the fifth field only if line start with the word `FILE`?

The word `FILE` could be located immediately in the begging of line or after space or TAB in the line.

Example of what I expected to get

```
  FILE=hosts   [PATH=/etc]
  FILE=network [PATH=/etc/sysconfig]
  FILE#TEST    [PATH=/etc/sysconfig]
```

I try this awk but doesn't work

```
awk '$1 == "^[[:blank:]]*FILE*" && '{print $1" "$5}'  file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$1 ~ /^FILE/ { print $1 " " $5 }'
```

Your method doesn't work because `==` checks for literal equality, not a regex; you need to use `~` for that.

Comment: but if FILE start after TAB or space then what need to add in your syntax?

Comment: @yael - You don't have to, as they are default field separators in `awk`. It should just work.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
awk '/^ *FILE=/{print $1, $5}'
```

or

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*FILE=/{print $1, $5}'
```

Comment: This will not work, as there is whitespace before `FILE`. It also doesn't match the comments as asked in the question.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: This still misses the line with `FILE#`.